# jQuery id does not yield text representation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, parameter-passing

I’d like to add a button to certain text fields to allow for additional input methods. Since the button should be able to reference the text field it belongs to, I'm adding a parameter to the function call within the button’s `onClick()` handler, containing the ID of the text field.

At least, this is my plan. When I obtain the ID of the text field, and display it in an alert, it displays nicely. However, when I use the result of `$(this).attr('id')` as a function parameter, I'd expect a string to be given to the function (the id of the element). Instead some weird object is given.

How do I convert that object to a string? Or is there a conceptual flaw?

```
<form>
<input class="joeDateTime" type="text" name="n1" id="n1" value="2014-09-01 17:30:00">
</form>

<script>
function handleJoeDateTime(e)
{
    alert('Edit '+e); // shows 'Edit [object HTMLInputElement]'
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.joeDateTime').each(function(){
        var i = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(i); // shows 'n1'
        $('<button onclick="handleJoeDateTime(' + i + ');return false;"></button>').insertAfter($(this));
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
$('<button onclick="handleJoeDateTime(' + i + ');return false;"></button>')
```

where this should be

```
$('<button onclick=\"handleJoeDateTime(\"' + i + '\");return false;\"></button>')
```

When you're passing an element to jQuery ( $ ), it becomes a jquery object.
It had been made to handle id, class, elements, not html chunks.
What you want is inserting a piece of concatenated elements as an html node.

so first concatenate  your elements then append it with the jQuery's `after()` method.
(or create/append it with vanilia js `var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");`)

```
 var Button = '<button class=\"AltBut\" id=\"' + i + '\"></button>';
 $(this).after(Button);
```

or ( for compacity )

```
$(this).after('<button class=\"AltBut\" id=\"' + i + '\"></button>');
```

In this exemple, I'm adding an id to each enabled buttons where I store your variable `i`

Then add a click listener to those buttons, avoid inline js at all price, for maintainability's sacke.

```
$('.AltBut').on('click',function(){
        var i = $(this).attr("id");
        alert("i= "+i);
        return false;
})
```

The whole demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/x6x4v90y/1/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my flaw, and even more for insight in proper style. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing `i` as a string value, you are passing it as an variable. In modern browsers the element's id are copied to properties of the window object(so you can access then as global variables).

So you need to enclose them using quotes to pass `i` as a string value

```
$('<button onclick="handleJoeDateTime(\'' + i + '\');return false;"></button>').insertAfter($(this));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2xtbd9pL/2/)

---

Also Instead of using inlined event handlers, I would recommend using jQuery event handlres

```
$('.joeDateTime').each(function () {
    var i = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(i); // shows 'n1'
    $('<button />', {
        text: '',
        click: function () {
            handleJoeDateTime(i);
            return false;
        }
    }).insertAfter(this);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2xtbd9pL/3/)